# adding a unique id and PK to existing tables

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql, ssis

i have a few tables that were created in mssql 2005 server. due to my inexperience at the time, the tables were created without a primary key or unqiquely identifying column.

how can i add a column with a unique id (auto incrememnt?) to a table with existing data (around 600k rows)?

i need this to be a Primary key so that i can start using SQL Analysis services.

Many thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In T-SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
```

But as Yaakov says, it's also very easy to do in SSMS.

Comment: Thankyou!! using SSMS times out due to the large number of rows generally and i prefer to use and learn the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

In T-SQL...

```
alter table TableName
add ID int identity(1,1) primary key not null
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the column through Sql Managemenent studio, set to int, auto-increment (1,1), not null and PK. When you save the table, the column will automatically be added and prepopulated with data.

Comment: could you help me out with the syntax? using '[ID] [int,auto-increment](1,1) not null,' and other variations arent working.

Answer (score 0):

Add column named `ID` and Give Type `UniqueIdentifier`, Make it as not nullable and Put Default value as `newid()`

Comment: For auto increment you can go with Yaakov Ellis option.